# Curl info returning HTTP code 404 for Instagram API

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Can you guys please help me to debug the issue?
we have integrated new Instagram API in our site

the get user media endpoint gives all the data as it should and gives permalink of the image some thing like this.
[permalink] => https://www.instagram.com/p/BhPF_wIF_LdKPD50yRBIziXRuNxoozgkbTfTNQ0/

So now we want low resolution ,medium resolution images url so we send a PHP curl call to this link
https://www.instagram.com/p/BhPF_wIF_LdKPD50yRBIziXRuNxoozgkbTfTNQ0/media/size=t

When we browse this link it's returning an image fine with redirected link of something like this:https://instagram.flhe5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.135.1080.1080a/s150x150/100892861_961026034341512_1655134161295915987_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.flhe5-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=c2ziC3PLbasdskAX82Pknl&oh=7b0f92ea582a88412471794c51ec6020&oe=5F722E4

we want this redirected link using curl call but somehow curl info returning HTTP code 404 every time. https://prnt.sc/u6uw8l so we can't get effective url through curl.

would be grateful if you guys could debug what could be the issue here.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the page you're trying to access exists? When I try to visit the urls mentioned in the post, I get protected content or page not found.

Comment: yes they exists for sure.